# Wrong Yes/No text using Android Resource String

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am building a dialog in Mono for Android like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
builder.SetTitle(Context.GetString(Resource.String.MyTitle));
builder.SetMessage(Context.GetString(Resource.String.MyQuestion);
//YES, not OK
builder.SetPositiveButton(Android.Resource.String.Yes, new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>((dlgSender, dlgEvt) => { doSomething();});
builder.SetNegativeButton(Context.GetString(Android.Resource.String.No), new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>((dlgSender, dlgEvt) => {    doSomethingElse();}));
builder.SetNeutralButton(Context.GetString(Android.Resource.String.Cancel), 
                                         new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>((dlgSender, dlgEvt) => {}));

Dialog dialog = builder.Create();
dialog.Show();
```

This brings up my question with three buttons: **"Cancel, Cancel, Ok"** whereas I expected to get **"No, Cancel, Yes"**. Is anything wrong with my code above or is there something wrong with Mono for Android here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`android.R.string.yes` and `android.R.string.no` (used as `Android.Resource.String.*` in Monodroid) are just resource names, which equate to "OK" and "Cancel". You'll have to make your own string resources.

From Android's `strings.xml` (Android 4.2):

> ```
> <!-- Preference framework strings. -->
> <string name="ok">OK</string>
> <!-- Preference framework strings. -->
> <string name="cancel">Cancel</string>
> <!-- Preference framework strings. -->
> <string name="yes">OK</string>
> <!-- Preference framework strings. -->
> <string name="no">Cancel</string>
> ```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Defining the two strings wouldn't be a problem if if were just one language, but that means I'll have to update a dozen strings.xml files...

Comment: @Philipp Yeah, unfortunately that's the way it goes. We can't really rely on Google's strings files for the most part.